# crashes on FIRCLSContext.m -- FIRCLSContextInitialize --- __FIRCLSContextInitialize_block_invoke -- [NSString stringWithUTF8String:] #8883

Tags: firebase

`2021-10-29 10:48:32.563387+0800 YoHo[49412:21422570] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSString stringWithUTF8String:]: NULL cString'
*** First throw call stack:

```
0 CoreFoundation 0x000000010f06fbb4 __exceptionPreprocess + 242
1 libobjc.A.dylib 0x0000000111adbbe7 objc_exception_throw + 48
2 Foundation 0x00000001124afe49 +[NSString stringWithBytes:length:encoding:] + 0
3 FirebaseCrashlytics 0x00000001105373f2 __FIRCLSContextInitialize_block_invoke.28 + 50
4 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000119727a28 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
5 libdispatch.dylib 0x0000000119728c0c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
6 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000011972b23f _dispatch_queue_override_invoke + 1466
7 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000011973ab44 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 403
8 libdispatch.dylib 0x000000011973b5ec _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 196
9 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000011b29247a _pthread_wqthread + 244
10 libsystem_pthread.dylib 0x000000011b291493 start_wqthread + 15
```

libc++abi: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException

The code is:

FIRCLSContext.m -- FIRCLSContextInitialize --

```
dispatch_group_async(group, queue, ^{
    NSString* rootPath = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:initData->previouslyCrashedFileRootPath];
    NSString* fileName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:FIRCLSCrashedMarkerFileName];
    _firclsContext.readonly->previouslyCrashedFileFullPath =
    FIRCLSContextAppendToRoot(rootPath, fileName);
});
```

The initData->previouslyCrashedFileRootPath is zero

I found the initData is a pointer to stack object, if the stack is change by others, the 'previouslyCrashedFileRootPath' may be zero or somethingelse.

```
FBRetainCycleDetector (0.1.4)
FBSDKCoreKit (9.1.0):
FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (= 9.1.0)
FBSDKCoreKit/Core (= 9.1.0)
FBSDKCoreKit/Basics (9.1.0)
FBSDKCoreKit/Core (9.1.0):
FBSDKCoreKit/Basics
FBSDKLoginKit (9.1.0):
FBSDKLoginKit/Login (= 9.1.0)
FBSDKLoginKit/Login (9.1.0):
FBSDKCoreKit (~> 9.1.0)
FBSDKShareKit (9.1.0):
FBSDKShareKit/Share (= 9.1.0)
FBSDKShareKit/Share (9.1.0):
FBSDKCoreKit (~> 9.1.0)
Firebase/Analytics (7.9.0):
Firebase/Core
Firebase/Core (7.9.0):
Firebase/CoreOnly
FirebaseAnalytics (~> 7.9.0)
Firebase/CoreOnly (7.9.0):
FirebaseCore (= 7.9.0)
Firebase/Crashlytics (7.9.0):
Firebase/CoreOnly
FirebaseCrashlytics (~> 7.9.0)
Firebase/Performance (7.9.0):
Firebase/CoreOnly
FirebasePerformance (~> 7.9.0)
FirebaseABTesting (7.11.0):
FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
FirebaseAnalytics (7.9.0):
FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
FirebaseInstallations (~> 7.0)
GoogleAppMeasurement (= 7.9.0)
GoogleUtilities/AppDelegateSwizzler (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/Network (~> 7.0)
"GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.0)"
nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)
FirebaseCore (7.9.0):
FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (~> 7.4)
GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.0)
FirebaseCoreDiagnostics (7.9.0):
GoogleDataTransport (~> 8.0)
GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/Logger (~> 7.0)
nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)
FirebaseCrashlytics (7.9.0):
FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
FirebaseInstallations (~> 7.0)
GoogleDataTransport (~> 8.0)
nanopb (~> 2.30907.0)
PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
FirebaseInstallations (7.11.0):
FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/UserDefaults (~> 7.0)
PromisesObjC (~> 1.2)
FirebasePerformance (7.9.0):
FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
FirebaseInstallations (~> 7.0)
FirebaseRemoteConfig (~> 7.0)
GoogleDataTransport (~> 8.2)
GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/ISASwizzler (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/MethodSwizzler (~> 7.0)
Protobuf (~> 3.12)
FirebaseRemoteConfig (7.11.0):
FirebaseABTesting (~> 7.0)
FirebaseCore (~> 7.0)
FirebaseInstallations (~> 7.0)
GoogleUtilities/Environment (~> 7.0)
"GoogleUtilities/NSData+zlib (~> 7.0)"
```

Please assist us in resolving this crash.`